# Access array in reverse order c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following piece of code

```
int array[3] = { 10, 15, 20};
```

How can I access its elements in reverse order, without reversing the indices. I mean index `0` would return the last element (20), and index `2` would return the first element (10).

```
array[0] // it would return 20
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't access enum this way... That being said, if you have 90 millions rows, maybe you'd want to use a data structure for that...

Comment: Distinguish `enum` and array.

Comment: This is not how an enum is used. Perhaps what you want is an array or list.

Comment: Its a beginner question! But i need to get things in reverse order, but i cant reverse the quotes. int quote [5] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 3 }; quote[0] returns 3;

Comment: @LeonardoHermoso you should save the size (i.e. `int size = 5`) and you can access it as `quote[size - 1]` to get the last element

Comment: @vu1p3n0x this is what i need! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a simple math question.  `array[n]` from the back is simply `array[array_size - 1 - n]` from beginning.

Personally I will make up a little wrapper for the array if similar logic needs to be used in more than 1 place.

Psuedo code looks like:

```
template <T> class reverse_array {
public:
    reverse_array(T* array, size_t size)
        : m_array(array), m_size(size) {}

    operator T& [] (size_t index) {
        return m_array[m_size - 1 - index];
    }

    operator const T& [] (size_t index) const {
        return m_array[m_size - 1 - index];
    }

private:
    T* m_array;
    size_t m_size;
}
```

so that you can do

```
int quote[3] = { 10 , 15 ,20};
reverse_array quote_in_reverse(quote, 3);

int result = quote_in_reverse[0]; // result = 20
```

Answer (score -2):

This may help you

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <algorithm>    
#include <vector>       
using namespace std;
int main () {
  vector<int> a;

  //Function goes here
  for (int i=0; i<=5; ++i){
      a.push_back(i);   //Values are: 0 1 2 3 4 5
  }
   // Reverse process
  (a.begin(), a.end());    // Values are: 5 4 3 2 1 0

  //Print the result
  for (vector<int>::iterator it=a.begin(); it!=a.end(); ++it)
  cout<<"new reverse 'a' is: "<<*it;

  return 0;
}
```

Another thing is that computer starts counting from 0. So you should give four values to your quote `int quote[3]={10, 20, 30, 40}`
quote[0] is 10
and quote [3] is 40.

Comment: `(a.begin(), a.end()); ` this is invalid expression, check it. If you use `STL` container there is available `std::rbegin()` and `std::rend()`, use them.